# IdentityServer4 with two Different Login Screens

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect, identityserver4, asp.net-identity-3

I have two user roles, role A and role B.

Role A is allowed to have a 3rd party authentication access (Facebook and Twitter) in addition to the default one.

Role B only allows the default login method (username and password).

Both roles should have different style pages as they are targeting different business users (so different images and css).

Is that supported by IdentityServer4 out of the box? Can you point me to some resources of how to achieve this? Is this supported by normal customisation (not by hacking it!)?

Comment: Where you define the roles for user?
I think you case needs a multi-tenant solution.

Comment: Each role has a standalone ASP.NET Core website (implemented as claims of type role). This is one system and the roles have a relationship, so it is not a multi-tenant problem.

Comment: So each role is a client?

Comment: If the distinction is the client they are using - that's easy. Simply read the client ID on the account controller and render different views. Check the quickstart UI.

Comment: @leastprivilege I did a proof of concept of this and it worked, thank you for your comments.

Comment: @MikeAnderson good suggestion, it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the best solution, if the multi-tenant approach does not work, is to provide roles in the ASP.NET style. Since you do not know the user's role when they first go to the web page, you will need to have two distinct logon pages that are triggered either by a URL or a user cookie.

This solution has one other limitation not faced by the multi-tenant approach. The security between the two roles is entirely up to your code. That is the weak link in most external attacks.

Comment: Actually, I know the role of the user before authenticating them.As each role lives on a different application and I can easily give each individual application an independent client id